# Qpython3 - syntaxerror при установке модулей через pip install

Tags: android, python-3.x, pip

Я так понимаю, что проблема с кодировкой, но я без понятия как решить её. Уже весь гугл просмотрел. При установке банального `requests` вылетает ошибка и не дает установиться, про `vk_api` я вообще молчу!
Ничего дополнительно не устанавливал, прога из коробки.

```
    /mnt/expand/6703dd0d-8749-4782-a664-a43f44da1598/user/0/org.qpython.qpy3/files/bin/qpython-android5.sh "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts3/pip_console.py" && exit
thon/scripts3/pip_console.py" && exit         <
Input pip commands, ie: pip install {module}
-->pip install requests
Downloading/unpacking requests
  Running setup.py egg_info for package requests
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/cache/pip-build/requests/setup.py", line 58, in <module>
        exec(f.read(), about)
      File "<string>", line 14
        __cake__ = u'\u2728 \U0001f370 \u2728'
                                             ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/cache/pip-build/requests/setup.py", line 58, in <module>

    exec(f.read(), about)

  File "<string>", line 14

    __cake__ = u'\u2728 \U0001f370 \u2728'

                                         ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /storage/emulated/0/qpython/cache/pip-build/requests
Storing complete log in /sdcard/qpython/.pip/pip.log
-->
```

Comment: Версию питона точно укажите.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja 3.2.2

Comment: Прикрепите, пожалуйста, текст ошибки вместо скриншота.

Comment: @user273361 удалите свой комментарий и отредактируйте само сообщение, вставив туда текст ошибки вместо скриншота.

Comment: @ahgpoug как то так

Comment: @ahgpoug ну что, есть догадки?

Answer (score 0):

В `Python 3.0` синтаксис строк `u'...'` был упразднен, и только в `Python 3.3` вернули обратно.

Насколько я помню.

Comment: И что мне делать? Не переходить же на 2.7

Comment: Похоже что так. `Requests officially supports Python 2.6–2.7 & 3.3–3.7`

Comment: да я не только про requests говорю, там все модули не могут установиться

Answer (score 0):

А вроде модули там устанавливаются через pip3

```
pip3 install requests
```